# The SQL Server (SQL_2K5) service terminated with service-specific error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have changed my windows 7 password when I started my laptop this morning. Tried to open SQL server management studio 2005 but found sql server instance service is not running. Checked in the windows system event log and seeing this message

> The SQL Server (SQL_2K5) service terminated with service-specific error WARNING: You have until SQL Server (SQL_2K5) to logoff. If you have not logged off at this time, your session will be disconnected, and any open files or devices you have open may lose data..

Sql server was working perfectly until last night. Also tried system restore incase something has changed but still seeing the same.

Also seeing this message

> Warning: You have until %1 to logoff. If you have not logged off at this time, your session will be disconnected, and any open files or devices you have open may lose data. [0x80070d59]

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Sounds like it is something related to the account that is running the SQL Server service.  What account is it using?

Comment: Its usnig LocalSystem I have also tried changing the account to LocalService in the built-in account list but still getting error

Comment: Also tried to start the service via Sql server configuration manager but getting this error message

"Consult the event log or other applicable erros logs for details"

Comment: `LocalSystem` should be ok.  Since it's your laptop, this is not something for production, right?  Can you try with a different login/account?  If you are a local admin on your laptop, try your own login.

Comment: I have tried that already. It does not make a difference either :( This is really strange,  never seen this error in my eight years of working with SQL server

Comment: Any recent changes to RAM for you SQL instance?

Comment: None as far as I can remember

Comment: Nothing has changed since last night apart from I changing the password. But that was restored few days back too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50049/discussion-between-dmason-and-learner)

Answer (score 2):

It could be related to NTFS access rights for local SQL account groups like *SQLServerMSSQLUser$YourHost$YourInstance*
For example, this account must have *Full Control* access level to *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf* and if it doesn't then you will have exactly same kind of error message.
It could be fixed manually or automatically via repair function from MS SQL installation package.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem the message was:

> WARNING: You have until SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) to logoff. If you have not logged off at this time, your session will be disconnected, and any open files or devices you have open may lose data.

My problem were that the Windows Disk Compression featured, compressed the directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server", after decompressing the directory the problem gone way.

Answer (score -1):

This usually occurs when the `master.mdf` or the `mastlog.ldf` gets corrupt . 
In order to solve the issue go to the following path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL` , there you will find a folder `Template Data` , copy the `master.mdf` and `mastlog.ldf` and replace it in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Data folder`.

That's it .

Now start the MS SQL service and you are done.

Comment: @RemusRusanu de ce zici ca e gresit daca eu asa am rezolvat problema aceasta? zi tu o solutia buna sa pornesti serverul